# Warning message displaying while disabling controls dynamically angular2

Tags: angular, disabled-control

I wanted to disable all the controls in page load, and enable all the controls when user clicked on add button in reactive forms. So to achieve this i used `[disabled]` attribute in html template, but I am getting  the below warning message in console.

> **Warning**:
>
> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form. If you set disabled to true
>         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>         you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

```
  Example: 


     form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl(
    {value: 'Nancy', disabled: true},Validators.required),
        last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      });
```

Please help me out how to avoid this warning message and achieve my requirement.

Comment: Doesn't the warning tell it all? Mixing template-driven forms with reactive forms is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

@GünterZöchbauer is correct, the warning is saying that you should programmatically enable/disable the controls either on creation as in the example or via the function `.disable()` and then enable with the `.enable()` function either per control or at the top level where it will propogate down (unless you specify false).

If you bind to `[disabled]` in a Reactive Form the behavior may not work as expected.

From the AbstractControl documentation:

> disable({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?:
>   boolean}) : void Disables the control. This means the control will be
>   exempt from validation checks and excluded from the aggregate value of
>   any parent. Its status is DISABLED.
>
> If the control has children, all children will be disabled to maintain
>   the model.
>
> enable({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?:
>   boolean}) : void Enables the control. This means the control will be
>   included in validation checks and the aggregate value of its parent.
>   Its status is re-calculated based on its value and its validators.
>
> If the control has children, all children will be enabled.